# Am I implementing ActiveMQ correctly? To achieve a transacted session and retry

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

I’m trying to come up with a JMS-ActiveMQ implementation that supports rollback using a transacted session.
I’m very new to ActiveMQ and Ive taken a first stab at the implementation using its Java libraries.

When I run my application I see that the messages are successfully enqueued and dequeued. I can also see that the corresponding DLQ is automatically generated. However, Im not sure whether I’ve configured the redeliverypolicy correctly. As of now its configured on the producer, but some [examples](http://xpadro.blogspot.com/2013/08/spring-jms-processing-messages-within.html) tie the redelivery policy to the listener-container so Im not entirely sure whether poisoned messages would be placed on the DLQ,in my case(if at all).  Detailed comments are in the snippets.

Also, all examples Ive encountered so far use Spring. However, I **dont** have the option of using it would require rewiring an entire project(Im open if it involves only minimal overhead).

Any insight on how I could do this in Java using ActiveMQ api’s would be greatly appreciated.

Producer

```
public void publishUpdate(final MessageBody payload)
            throws JMSException {
        Session session = session(connection());
        try {
            Message message = message(session, payload);
            LOGGER.info("About to put message on queue");
            producer(session).send(message);
            // without session.commit()-- no messages get put on the queue.
            session.commit();// messages seem to be enqueued now.
            
        } catch ( BadRequestException e) { //to avoid badly formed requests?
            LOGGER.info("Badly formed request. Not attempting retry!");
            return;
        } catch (JMSException jmsExcpetion) {

            LOGGER.info("Caught JMSException will retry");
            session.rollback();// assume rollback is followed by a retry?
        }         
    }

  private MessageProducer producer(Session session) throws JMSException {
        return session.createProducer(destination());
    }

   private Connection connection() throws JMSException {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory= new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
     connectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(getRedeliveryPolicy());//redelivery policy with three retries and redelivery time of 1000ms  
        return connection;
    }

 private Session session(Connection connection) throws JMSException {
        Session session = connection.createSession(true,
                Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
        connection.start();
        return session;
    }
```

Listener:

```
public class UpdateMessageListener implements MessageListener{
….
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        String json = null;
        try {
            //Does the listener need to do anything to deal with retry?
            json = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
            MessageBody request = SerializeUtils.deserialize(json, MessageBody.class);
            processTransaction(request.getUpdateMessageBody(), headers);//perform some additional processing.
            } catch (Throwable e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error processing request: {}", json);
        }
    }
}
```

Consumer :

```
  private MessageConsumer consumer() throws JMSException {
        LOGGER.info("Creating consumer");
            MessageConsumer consumer = session().createConsumer(destination());
            consumer.setMessageListener(new UpdateMessageListener()); //wire listener to consumer
        return consumer;
    }
    private Session session() throws JMSException {
        Connection connection=connection();
         Session session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);//create an auto-ack  from the consumer side? Is this correct?
         connection.start();
         return session;
  }
```

I'm also open to providing more code if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution has a little flaw.

According to [JMS document](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Session.html?is-external=true#AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE), failed execution message will be redeliver by message queue(such as ActiveMQ) in Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE mode if it exists an excepiton in onMessage function. But that flow was broken, because listener catch Throwable or Exception in onMessage function. The dataflow is shown as below picture:
[image]

[ACK_TYPE](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/activemq/command/MessageAck.html)

If you want to implement local transaction, it should throw exception when message handler execute with failure. In pesudo code, an asynchronous redelivery message consumer may be like below:

```
Session session = connection.getSession(consumerId);  
sessionQueueBuffer.enqueue(message);  
Runnable runnable = new Ruannale(){  
    run(){  
        Consumer consumer = session.getConsumer(consumerId);  
        Message md = sessionQueueBuffer.dequeue();  
        try{  
            consumer.messageListener.onMessage(md);  
            ack(md);//send an STANDARD_ACK_TYPE, tell broker success
        }catch(Exception e){  
            redelivery();//send redelivery ack. DELIVERED_ACK_TYPE, require broker keep message and redeliver it.
    }  
}   
threadPool.execute(runnable);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Produce side transactions are only generally used as part of a distributed transaction. If this publisher is the origin, then no need to take the overhead.
2. You can't do a transaction with a MessageListener b/c you don't have a handle to the session. You have to fall back to a receive() loop. Check out.. use the ActiveMQSession to get INDIVIDUAL_MESSAGE acknowledgement mode for a nifty per-message transaction mode.